# How to create KVO Observables in ReactiveKit

Tags: ios, swift3, reactivekit

I'm migrating my project from swift 2.3 to swift 3.
After days of work I'm left only with one error relating Bond/ReactiveKit.

Before the migration I used the following code to create KVO Observables:

```
var myObservable : Observable<Set<String>?>!
myObservable = Observable<Set<String>?>(object: myObj, keyPath: "my_path")
```

On Bond/ReactiveKit V4.x I was able to use the code above because Bond extended Observable and the following init method was added

```
public convenience init(object: NSObject, keyPath: String)
```

On Bond V5.x the extension was removed and I can't figure out a solution for this issue. 
I tried to extend Observable using `extension ReactiveExtensions where Base: Observable<Set<String>?>` which didn't work. 
I tried using `SafePublishSubject` but also without success.

Does any body have an idea how to create KVO Observables using Bond/ReactiveKit with Swift 3?